# Why is my contract not deploying on the Sepolia testnet? It shows that the Sepolia network doesn't exist

Tags: contract-deployment, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

[image: code]
[image]

am encountering an issue with deploying my contract on Hardhat. The error message indicates that the Sepolia network does not exist. I have provided links to screenshots of the error messages for better understanding: Screenshot 1 and Screenshot 2.

I would appreciate any insights or guidance on how to resolve this problem. If there are specific configurations or adjustments that need to be made to deploy contracts on Hardhat with the Sepolia network, please provide instructions or suggestions.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: What's the command you are running, also put the private key inside in array.

Answer (score 0):

Set the correct values for `url` and other `keys` in the configuration. Url can be specified personal (e.g. from infura) or general public.
Public RPC addresses can be obtained here: https://chainlist.org/
For sepolia, for example, it could be `url: "https://ethereum-sepolia.publicnode.com"`

Answer (score 0):

Hoping you are correctly importing both the RPC URL and Private Key from the env file. There is still a problem, with how you pass the private key to accounts.

```js
sepolia: {
  url: SEPOLIA_RPC_URL,
  accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY]
},
```

You can check the [Hardhat documentation](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-runner/docs/config) for more details.